# Hiding dynamically created Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to hide dynamically created arrays from the page source? I mean, when a user does a "view page source", he should not see all the values of the javascript array (looks quite ugly, not to mention the answers are visible).

Here is what I am doing:

1. Fetch the data from DB (e.g. multiple questions)
2. Create the javascript array with the questions
3. Use javascript to cycle through the questions one at a time

There are 4 reasons for doing this:

1. There should be zero lag between the questions (doesnt matter if it takes some time to load all the questions)
2. There are shared variables (e.g. a countdown timer) between the questions
3. Each question maybe "reviewed" immediately (hence the need for the correct answers).
4. All the questions and the user answers are again displayed for review at the end.

Is there are better way of doing that than what I am doing? I think there should be.

Comment: `Is it possible to hide dynamically created arrays from the page source` You can 'see' the data not only from the 'view page source'. Did you try to press F12 in IE, ctrl+shift+I in Chrome and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Ajax to fetch the data, it will not be seen by those viewing "page source".

Comment: Do you mean fetch each question individually? Because that would not work (need 0 lag)

Comment: No. Fetch the whole array, just as you are doing on the backend.

Comment: thanks a lot! I had not known that ajax requests do not show up on the source.